# Is the Neo4j plugin broken or is Grails 2.4.4?

Tags: database, grails, neo4j, grails-plugin

I have a Grails 2.4.4 app and when I try to install Neo4j by means of [the plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/neo4j), I get this:

```
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.neo4j:neo4j-jdbc:jar:2.0.2 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.neo4j:neo4j-jdbc:jar:2.0.2 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.neo4j:neo4j-jdbc:jar:2.0.2 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Could not find artifact org.neo4j:neo4j-jdbc:jar:2.0.2 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
```

This is the relevant output from `grails dependency-report`:

```
+--- org.grails.plugins:neo4j:2.0.0-M02
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-neo4j:2.0.0-M02
|    >>>> org.neo4j:neo4j-jdbc:2.0.2
|    \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-community:2.0.3
|         \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:2.0.3
|              \--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:1.1.1
|         \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:2.0.3
|              \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:3.6.2
|         \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-algo:2.0.3
|         \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-udc:2.0.3
|         \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-matching:2.0.3
|         \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher:2.0.3
|              \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-commons:2.0.3
|              \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9:2.0.3
|              \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0:2.0.3
|                   \--- org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.10:1.1.6
|                        \--- org.parboiled:parboiled-core:1.1.6
|                   \--- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.0
|              \--- org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3
|         \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-jmx:2.0.3
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support:2.0.7.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-web:2.0.7.RELEASE
```

(The `>>>> org.neo4j:neo4j-jdbc:2.0.2` line is highlighted in red.)

Is there another version of the plugin that would work? Or a newer version of Grails? Or do I just need a newer version of some coffee?

Answer (score 2):

The Neo4j JDBC driver is not available via Maven central. Instead it can be found on http://m2.neo4j.org/. So you need `repositories` closure in `BuildConfig.groovy` amend:

```
mavenRepo 'http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/'
```

Comment: That gives me: `Error Could not find artifact org.neo4j:neo4j-community:zip:2.0.3 in m2_neo4j_org_releases (http://m2.neo4j.org/releases)
| Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.`